# Facebook JS SDK Token expiration time

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-access-token

Why every time I reload a page of my site (made with JS SDK), Facebook gives me a different Token?

Does token expires in an hour?

Comment: Why downvoting? And no answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Facebook's documentation:

> User access tokens come in two forms: short-lived tokens and
>   long-lived tokens. **Short-lived** tokens usually have a lifetime of about
>   **an hour or two**, while long-lived tokens usually have a lifetime of
>   about 60 days. You should not depend on these lifetimes remaining the
>   same - the lifetime may change without warning or expire early.

Hope this clarifies things.

Comment: I Think that every time I reload the page I request a new token.

Comment: you should avoid storing access tokens anyway, and you do not need to worry about tokens at all while using the js sdk - at least in most cases.